# I'm trying to make an event listener that makes it to where when you click on an image it makes a div appear

Tags: javascript

#HTML#

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DEM0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DEMO</h1>
    <div class="c-container">
        <img class="active" id="testCase" src="/scrawny_still.png" alt="#">
        <div class="o-container">
            <img id="open" src="/Scrawny.gif" alt="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#Java Script#

```
var testCase = document.getElementById("testCase");

testCase.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    console.log("Anim AC");
    var openCase = this.getElementsByClassName("o-container");
    if(openCase.style.display === "none") {
        openCase.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
        openCase.style.display = "none"; 
    }
});
```

Css has no issues I get this error whenever I run code in my live preview :

app.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
at HTMLImageElement. (app.js:6)

Comment: Method `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements and does not have the `style` property. Capture the single `o-container` element you have using `var openCase = this.querySelector(".o-container");`. Note the class selector needs a dot (`.o-container`) to refer to a style class.

Comment: You could also write the CSS so that it's white (invisible) but on :active, you make it a visible color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this error:

```
app.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined at HTMLImageElement. (app.js:6)
```

indicates that whatever expression comes before `display` on that line is currently returning `undefined`.

In your case, `openCase.style` is `undefined`.

What that doesn't tell you is what `openCase` is. If you were to add `console.log(openCase)` above the error that could give you a bit of insight.
If you run something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')
HTMLCollection []
```

You can see that you get an empty HTMLCollection back. So, if you were to call `style` on that, you would get undefined.
From that, you can see that this line of code is the one that isn't doing what it's supposed to:

```
var openCase = this.getElementsByClassName("o-container");
```

The reason for that is that you've currently got `this` there and `this` will be referring to the `image` that you've attached the event listener to.
So, when you look through `getElementsByClassName` it won't find the `o-container` element, because it's not a child of the image. You can use `node.parentElement` to get the parent and then find the child node inside of the parent using querySelector.

Try something like this:

```js
var testCase = document.getElementById("testCase");

testCase.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("Anim AC");
  var openCase = this.parentElement.querySelector(".o-container");
  if (openCase.style.display === "none") {
    openCase.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    openCase.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

You can check it out in codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-volhard-hn2o3?file=/app.js:0-416

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class for your selector on the hidden element, this will return a group of elements.  ***querySelector*** ***(returns the first element that matches your selector)***.

In the example I provided, `querySelector()` will give you the first iteration of the element with the class selector used. Further more I suggest using CSS for the CSS styling rather than JS. You can easily toggle a class, initially adding the hidden state using CSS. If you wish to remove the display none without the ability to reinstate the display none property, you can use el.classList.remove('classThatHidesElement').

```js
const testCase = document.getElementById('testCase');
const oCont = document.querySelector('.o-container');

testCase.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  oCont.children[0].classList.toggle('hide')  
})
```

```css
#testCase, #open {
  width: 400px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#testCase2, #open2 {
  width: 400px;
}

.hide2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Using querySelector just gets the first element in the nodeList
<div class="c-container">
  <img class="active" id="testCase" src="https://www.openimagedenoise.org/images/moana_16spp_oidn.jpg" alt="#">
  <div class="o-container">
    <img id="open" class="hide" src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/24/23/T7P10I.jpg" alt="#">
  </div>
</div>
```